# JQUery Hide DIV clicking outside the DIV

Tags: jquery, hide

Let's assume i have the following control :

```
   <div class="slControlWrapper">
        <div class="slControlLabel">
            <asp:Label ID="lblSL" CssClass="lblSL" runat="server">Clickable Label</asp:Label>
        </div>
        <div class="slControlSeparator">
            <img alt="" src="../Images/pxlGray.gif" style="width: 1px; height: 29px" />
        </div>
        <div class="slControlDropDown">
            <img alt="Clickable DropDown image" src="../Images/btDropDownCharcoal.gif" style="width: 23px; height: 29px" />
        </div>
         <div id="wndSL">
            This is the hidden content of my DIV Window
        </div>
    </div>
```

By default the wndSL has 
style= " display:none;     background-color: blue;    height:500px;    width:590px;"

I am able to show the wndSL when I click either slControlLabel or slControlDropDown. 
However I also need to hide it when I click either on the slControlLabel or slControlDropDown or anywhere outside the wndSL outside .

Can anyone help me how to figure out how to hide it, clicking anywhere outside my wndSL.

This is what I have so far... and I need to add the piece to hide it whenever i click outside the window

Thanks

```
 $('.slControlLabel, .slControlDropDown').bind('click',function(event){
       alert('This will open the wndSL'); 
       $('#wndSL').show(); 
 });
```

**New Problem** Revision 2

Here is the DIV i have now and as you will see I have more controls in there... so the origiinal answer does not work anymore because, when I click on the control within the DIV, it still closes the DIV.... So although my original request was to close when you click outside the DIV works , when i addded controls within the DIV, my condition to hide does not work... How can I tweak it so that anything within the DIV when clicked will not close the window (except the close button icoRedX.gif on the header )

This is my control

```
    <div class="wndShoppingList" id="wndShoppingList" style="display: block; ">
<div id="ctl00_ctl00_phContent_DynamicUserControl_Step_1_pnlWndShoppingListContentPanel" style="display: block; "><div id="ctl00_phContent_DynamicUserControl_Step_1_pnlWndShoppingListContent">
<div class="tableContainer">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="slHeaderLeft">
            Select a Saved Shopping List
            </div>
            <div class="slHeaderRight">
            <a id="ctl00_phContent_DynamicUserControl_Step_1_btClose" class="RadButton RadButton_Default rbImageButton" href="javascript:void(0)" style="display:inline-block;height:20px;width:18px;background-image:url(/APPSERVER0001/Images/icoDeleteGrayX.gif);line-height:20px;line-height:20px;height:20px;"><span class="rbText rbHideElement" style="width:100%;padding-left:0;padding-right:0;"></span><input id="ctl00_phContent_DynamicUserControl_Step_1_btClose_ClientState" name="ctl00_phContent_DynamicUserControl_Step_1_btClose_ClientState" type="hidden" autocomplete="off"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="details">
            <div class="gridDescription">
            Select a saved Shopping List to open. The list you already have open will be automatically  saved
            </div>
            <div class="gridContainer">
                <div id="ctl00_ctl00_phContent_DynamicUserControl_Step_1_pnlTemplateShoppingListPanel">
                    <div id="ctl00_phContent_DynamicUserControl_Step_1_pnlTemplateShoppingList">
                        <div id="ctl00_phContent_DynamicUserControl_Step_1_grdTemplateShoppingList" class="RadGrid RadGrid_Default" style="height:300px;" tabindex="0">
                                <table cellspacing="0" class="rgMasterTable" id="ctl00_phContent_DynamicUserControl_Step_1_grdTemplateShoppingList_ctl00" style="width:100%;table-layout:auto;empty-cells:show;">
                                <colgroup>
                                <col>
                                <col>
                                <col>
                                <col>
                                </colgroup>
                                <thead>
                                <tr style="display:none;">
                                <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th><th scope="col">&nbsp;</th><th scope="col">&nbsp;</th><th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead><tbody>
                                <tr class="rgRow" id="ctl00_phContent_DynamicUserControl_Step_1_grdTemplateShoppingList_ctl00__0">
                                <td><input type="image" name="ctl00$phContent$DynamicUserControl_Step_1$grdTemplateShoppingList$ctl00$ctl04$gbcSelectColumn" id="ctl00_phContent_DynamicUserControl_Step_1_grdTemplateShoppingList_ctl00_ctl04_gbcSelectColumn" src="../Images/btSelectCharcoal.gif" style="border-width:0px;"></td><td>
                                <span id="ctl00_phContent_DynamicUserControl_Step_1_grdTemplateShoppingList_ctl00_ctl04_lblTemplateName">Master Shopping List</span><br>
                                <span id="ctl00_phContent_DynamicUserControl_Step_1_grdTemplateShoppingList_ctl00_ctl04_lblLastUpdated"> Updated August 10, 2011</span>
                                </td><td>16 items</td><td><input type="image" name="ctl00$phContent$DynamicUserControl_Step_1$grdTemplateShoppingList$ctl00$ctl04$gbcDeleteColumn" id="ctl00_phContent_DynamicUserControl_Step_1_grdTemplateShoppingList_ctl00_ctl04_gbcDeleteColumn" src="../Images/icoDeleteRedX.gif" onclick="if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this list ?'))return false;" style="border-width:0px;"></td>
                                </tr><tr class="rgAltRow" id="ctl00_phContent_DynamicUserControl_Step_1_grdTemplateShoppingList_ctl00__1">
                                <td><input type="image" name="ctl00$phContent$DynamicUserControl_Step_1$grdTemplateShoppingList$ctl00$ctl06$gbcSelectColumn" id="ctl00_phContent_DynamicUserControl_Step_1_grdTemplateShoppingList_ctl00_ctl06_gbcSelectColumn" src="../Images/btSelectCharcoal.gif" style="border-width:0px;"></td><td>
                                <span id="ctl00_phContent_DynamicUserControl_Step_1_grdTemplateShoppingList_ctl00_ctl06_lblTemplateName">Audrey's Birthday Party</span><br>
                                <span id="ctl00_phContent_DynamicUserControl_Step_1_grdTemplateShoppingList_ctl00_ctl06_lblLastUpdated">Shopped August 2, 2011 for $49.11</span>
                                </td><td>11 items</td><td><input type="image" name="ctl00$phContent$DynamicUserControl_Step_1$grdTemplateShoppingList$ctl00$ctl06$gbcDeleteColumn" id="ctl00_phContent_DynamicUserControl_Step_1_grdTemplateShoppingList_ctl00_ctl06_gbcDeleteColumn" src="../Images/icoDeleteRedX.gif" onclick="if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this list ?'))return false;" style="border-width:0px;"></td>
                                </tr><tr class="rgRow" id="ctl00_phContent_DynamicUserControl_Step_1_grdTemplateShoppingList_ctl00__2">
                                <td><input type="image" name="ctl00$phContent$DynamicUserControl_Step_1$grdTemplateShoppingList$ctl00$ctl08$gbcSelectColumn" id="ctl00_phContent_DynamicUserControl_Step_1_grdTemplateShoppingList_ctl00_ctl08_gbcSelectColumn" src="../Images/btSelectCharcoal.gif" style="border-width:0px;"></td><td>
                                <span id="ctl00_phContent_DynamicUserControl_Step_1_grdTemplateShoppingList_ctl00_ctl08_lblTemplateName">Monthly Household Supplies</span><br>
                                <span id="ctl00_phContent_DynamicUserControl_Step_1_grdTemplateShoppingList_ctl00_ctl08_lblLastUpdated">Updated February 22, 2011</span>
                                </td><td>8 items</td><td><input type="image" name="ctl00$phContent$DynamicUserControl_Step_1$grdTemplateShoppingList$ctl00$ctl08$gbcDeleteColumn" id="ctl00_phContent_DynamicUserControl_Step_1_grdTemplateShoppingList_ctl00_ctl08_gbcDeleteColumn" src="../Images/icoDeleteRedX.gif" onclick="if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this list ?'))return false;" style="border-width:0px;"></td>
                                </tr>
                                </tbody>        
                                </table>
                                <input id="ctl00_phContent_DynamicUserControl_Step_1_grdTemplateShoppingList_ClientState" name="ctl00_phContent_DynamicUserControl_Step_1_grdTemplateShoppingList_ClientState" type="hidden" autocomplete="off">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

This is the JS

```
function OnPageLoad(){
window.$ = $telerik.$;
var t;
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.slControlLabel, .slControlDropDown').bind('click',function(event){
    $('#wndShoppingList').show();  
    event.stopPropagation(); 
});

// OnClick Event outside the wndShoppinglist.
// $('html').click(function(event){  Tried  this as well 
if((event.target.id != 'wndShoppingList')){  // This used to work but after adding controls in the DIV, this returns the ID of the controls within the DIV
     alert('click on body '+ event.target.id)
     alert('about to hide')
     $('#wndShoppingList').hide(); 
});

});   //End $(document).ready()
}
Sys.Application.add_load(OnPageLoad);
```

Answer (score 2):

Bind a click event to `html` to capture any click made, and make it hide the `#wndSL`

```
$("html").click(function() {
    $("#wndSL").hide();
});
```

Then override that on your `#wndSL`'s click event using `.stopPropagation();`

```
$("#wndSL").click(function (event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your input... question though... is there any reason why you would choose the html selector vs the body... just wondering... because ive used body... thinking it will be the same as html... since i cant physically click within the head of an html

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

Html

```
<div class="slControlWrapper">
        <div class="slControlLabel">
            <asp:Label ID="lblSL" CssClass="lblSL" runat="server">Clickable Label</asp:Label>
        </div>
        <div class="slControlSeparator">
            <img alt="" src="../Images/pxlGray.gif" style="width: 1px; height: 29px" />
        </div>
        <div class="slControlDropDown">
            <img alt="Clickable DropDown image" src="../Images/btDropDownCharcoal.gif" style="width: 23px; height: 29px" />
        </div>
         <div id="wndSL">
            This is the hidden content of my DIV Window
        </div>
        <div id="test">
        I am for test click on me
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#wndSL {

display:none;     background-color: blue;    height:500px;    width:590px;
}
```

Jquery

```
$('.slControlLabel, .slControlDropDown').bind('click',function(event){
       alert('This will open the wndSL');
       $('#wndSL').show();
     event.stopPropagation();
 });

$('html').click(function() {
   $('#wndSL').hide();
});
```

And here is [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nCZmz/9/)

Comment: i need some more help after i applied modifications and actuial content

Answer (score 0):

```
$("body").click
(
  function(e)
  {
    if(e.target.id != "wndSL")
    {
      $("#wndSL").hide();
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: just a typo on the comparison "!=" and missing the stopPropagation() on my function to show... otherwise it will bubble up and close the div right away Otherwise, i've used it for hiding...and added the missing StopPropagation Thanks...